# Can we get credentials of a google console project by making an API call and not by going in google console and manually creating them?

Tags: push-notification, gmail-api, credentials, google-console-developer

I am working on gmail-push-notifications and where I have to create a project in google console and then I have to create credentials for that project manually and using those credentials. Now I don't want to create credentials manually by going into google console. I am looking for an API call which I can make to get the credentials of a project.

Can anyone suggest me an api for creating credentials for google project.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's possible. As per this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), you need to obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials from the Google API Console. After you obtain the client email address and private key from the API Console, you need to create a `GoogleCredential` object from the service account's credentials and the scopes your application needs access to.